# Must be one of: RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, RecyclerView.VERTICAL

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

After upgrading into AndroidX i am getting this error "**Must be one of: RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, RecyclerView.VERTICAL**" when i setting the LayoutManager

`tournamentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`

*Issue id: WrongConstant.*

*Inspection info:Ensures that when parameter in a method only allows a specific set of constants, calls obey those rules*

Comment: You are trying to do an extra job, check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the warning suggests change `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` into `RecyclerView.VERTICAL`it will work perfectly

for sample :

`tournamentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));`

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to vertically place items in `RecyclerView` which is the default behavior for `LinearLayout`

Change this

```
tournamentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

to this

```
tournamentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Comment: This isn't working if you want `Horizontal` so if you want `Horizontal` use `RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL`